# stopping html5 audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I write a function that stops ALL instances of playing html5 audio in the DOM?

html5 audio

```
<audio class="AudioPlayerV1" preload="none" width="292">
    <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

js

```
AudioPlayerV1('*').each(function() {
    this.setStop();
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$.each($('audio'), function () {
    this.pause();
});
```

This just finds all the `<audio>` elements in the DOM and uses the standard API to pause the playback for each.

Here's some excellent reading about `<audio>` and `<video>` tags: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

### Update

The documentation for the `AudioPlayerV1` script states this is how you pause an `<audio>` element:

```
$('#audio_id').AudioPlayerV1('pause');
```

*Source: http://1.s3.envato.com/files/14653378/index.html#how-to-use*

It looks like the `AudioPlayerV1` plugin is supposed to be called on a selection of DOM element(s) and passed in an option.

### Update

To run the plugin to pause multiple `<audio>` elements you should be able to do this:

```
$('audio').AudioPlayerV1('pause');
```

Which selects the `<audio>` elements in the DOM and passes them to the `AudioPlayerV1` plugin. the plugin should be written to handle this but if it isn't then you have to call the plugin on each element. Inside a loop would be easiest:

```
$.each($('audio'), function () {
    $(this).AudioPlayerV1('pause');
});
```

Comment: is there a way to just stop them all instead of pinpointing by id

Comment: For all HTML5 audio this works

    //stop all playing audio
    $.each($('audio'), function () {
    this.pause();
    });

Answer (score 1):

first you have to set an id for your audio element

in your js :

`var ply = document.getElementById('player');`

`var oldSrc = ply.src;`// just to remember the old source

`ply.src = "";`// to stop the player you have to replace the source with nothing

Comment: Very bad habit. How would you re-use your player? consider .pause() then .currentTime = 0;

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. `.stop()` threw an error.

```
$.each($('audio'), function () {
    this.pause();
});
```