# jQuery IE, how to stop <embed> element

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently trying to play different wav files on my website.  I am currently using the HTML5 `<audio>` element, but I'm also trying to get some backward compatibility since IE wont play wavs via the audio tag.

I have created a javascript function that creates the appropriate sound `<embed>` object:

```
function createPreHtml5EmbedItem(callID, parent) {
            $("#sound").remove();
            var sound = $("<embed id='sound' controls='console' type='audio/wav' />");
            sound.attr('src', '/recording?id=' + callID);
            sound.attr('loop', false);
            sound.attr('hidden', false);
            sound.attr('autostart', true);
            parent.append(sound);
}
```

This all works fine, but when I click a different button I would like to stop this audio element from playing.  In firefox i can do this:

```
function stopAudioPreHtml5() {
    $("#sound").remove();
}
```

but for some reason this does not work in IE.  Is there a way to stop the currently playing `<embed>` element before I remove it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283656/stopping-html5-audio Looks like someone had the same problem you had. They got the solution on the first answer, last update.

Answer (score 5):

For IE, you could use `.stop()` method to stop it.

***[The DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ugqyc/3/)***

```
function stopAudioPreHtml5() {
    var sound = $("#sound");
    if ($.browser.msie) {
       sound[0].stop();
    }
    sound.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe put your Soundfile in an iframe, and remove the whole iframe with jquery?!

Answer (score 0):

```
function createPreHtml5EmbedItem(callID, parent) {
            $("#sound").remove();
            var sound = $("<embed id='sound' controls='console' type='audio/wav' />");
            sound.attr('src', '/recording?id=' + callID);
            sound.attr('loop', false);
            sound.attr('hidden', false);
            sound.attr('autostart', true);
            $(parent).append(sound);
}
```

changed append line and works well for me. By the way, if you use .stop() and if you have so many embed objects on the page, it will cause performance problems. But remove() will not.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems in IE when I have an element that is the same as a javascript variable name.

In this case your variable `sound` and the element you create with an id of `sound`

I would try using a different variable name when creating and adding all the attributes to the object such as

```
var soundIE = $("<embed id='sound' controls='console' type='audio/wav' />");

soundIE.attr('src', '/recording?id=' + callID);
soundIE.attr('loop', false);
soundIE.attr('hidden', false);
soundIE.attr('autostart', true);
$(parent).append(soundIE);
```